# Looking for a good book on Morse-Bott functions.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, symplectic-geometry, morse-theory

I am looking for a book to study for the first time Morse-Bott functions. Does anyone know one that is easy to follow and detailed? If there is one connecting this subject with symplectic geometry, it would be useful too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The article [*Cascades and perturbed Morse-Bott functions*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.4609v1) by A. Banyaga and D. Hurtubise is quite nice and relatively easy to read. Other useful references are:

- *Morse-Bott theory and equivariant cohomology* by D.M. Austin and P.J. Braam. It appears in the [Floer memorial volume](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3034899483).
- Appendix C of Urs Frauenfelder's PhD [thesis](https://doi.org/10.3929/ethz-a-004485840), especially in connection with Floer-theory.
- Appendix A of [*The Arnold-Givental conjecture and moment Floer homology*](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0309373v1) by Urs Frauenfelder.

I think that all of these references relate Morse-Bott theory to symplectic geometry and in particular to Floer-theory.